# Android pause async task after network lost

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using an `AsyncTask` where I download images using `HttpUrlConnection`.Im using a `BroacastReciever` to listen to connectivity changes. I want to know how I can pause it when network is lost and continue it after regaining the connectivity. It would be helpful if anyone can provide some snippet/code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, `AsyncTask` **cannot be paused**.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) says that they can be run once and only once. So if you are trying to pause and resume an AsyncTask, it would lead to an `IllegalStateException`.

**What you can do :**

Inside your `doInBackground()`, keep checking for network connectivity after a certain time interval. When network is not available, cancel it and save the data in your application cache. Start a timer to keep on checking for network after certain timeout. When network is back again, start a fresh AsyncTask from where you left off (to be determined what you have in the cache). The last part is what I am not sure about, because you would need markers from the server as to how much you already have downloaded and how much is left. I don't think all servers provide that, which is evident from the fact that some downloads are resumable while some are not.

Another *very dirty* way would be put your **background thread to sleep when you lose network connectivity**.

Something like :

```
if(networkConnectivity == false)
do
{

   sleep(5000); // pauses the thread for 5 seconds

}while(networkConnectivity == false);
```

Comment: So can you please tell me how can I handle network connectivity issues when async task is running?

Comment: Updated my answer. The second solution is easier and more viable. Whereas the former one would have the perfect and clean one.